# why ack packets have such high payload

Tags: tcp, wireshark

[image]

When I was doing my network lab, I catched these tcp packets. I use gns3 to simulate the network, use the iperf3 to generate tcp packets.

```
iperf3 -c 10.0.3.33 -t 30
```

I do not know why there are so many ack packets, as well as high ack payload.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming. It should be better asked at [networkengineering.se]. Apart from that: these are not ACK packets which have a high payload but these are normal data packets which also have the ACK bit set and point to the latest sequence they've received. Perfectly normal behavior and fundamental to how TCP works.

Answer (score 0):

**Piggybacking of acknowledments**:The ACK for the last received packet need not be sent as a new packet, but gets a free ride on the next outgoing data frame(using the ACK field in the frame header). The technique is temporarily delaying outgoing ACKs so that they can be hooked on the next outgoing data frame is known as piggybacking. But ACK can't be delayed for a long time if receiver(of the packet to be acknowledged) does not have any data to send.